# Error in connection when building image with Minikube

Tags: docker, docker-compose, minikube

I've downloaded Minikube and I'm using it in my application.
I've prepared my local docker command to use the one provided by minikube with `eval $(minikube docker-env)”`

Finally, I'm using docker-compose with commands like `docker-compose build myimage` and I'm getting the following error:

`failed to get status: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing unable to upgrade to h2c, received 404"`

Any idea what could we the problem? Except this, I find that docker-compose and docker is behaving as I was expecting

The relevant section of the docker-compose.yml is

```
myservice:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  image: myimage
```

And for the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y upgrade && \
    apt-get -y install \
    build-essential \
    gettext-base \
    libffi-dev \
    libldap2-dev \
    libmagic1 \
    libsasl2-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxmlsec1-dev \
    libxslt1-dev \
    libyaml-dev \
    pkg-config \
    && \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN pip install --upgrade pip pipenv && rm -rf ~/.cache/pip
ENV PYTHONPATH=/opt/app/src:/opt/app/src/vendor
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
COPY build/Pipfile build/Pipfile.lock /tmp/
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN pipenv install --system && rm -rf ~/.cache/pip{,env,-tools}
```

Also, I want to insist that this works perfectly when using it locally. It's only when I try to use it on minikube when it starts failing

Comment: Can you share the Dockerfile and docker-compose, on how to replicate?

Comment: I've just edited the question with that info @JinnaBalu

Answer (score 0):

According to the information I found in [github](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37959#issuecomment-428311554) there are two possible causes for this behavior, one user is getting the same error as you and turning off the ‘Experimental Features’ options solved the issue, another user had to [downlevel](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37959#issuecomment-949035083) the docker version and rebuild the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue building within Gitlab CI building on a Debian 11 image, docker 20.10.5 and compose 2.5.1.

I was able to work around it by setting `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0` in the build environment.